# Is it possible to remap command to control when connecting to a computer remotely?

Tags: keyboard, remote-access

I regularly, out of muscle memory, select command when I remote in from a Mac to a Windows computer, which brings up the Start menu. Is it possible to remap this key to something more useful in Windows, or even to do nothing, when I use a program like Splashtop?

Comment: Microsoft's macOS version of RDC remaps for you, for most operations that use Cmd vs Ctrl, like cut copy paste etc. The one it doesn't is just Cmd on its own, when it acts like the Win Key.

Comment: Thanks, if you post this as a solution, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's macOS version of RDC remaps for you, for most operations that use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  vs  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  , like cut copy paste etc. The one it doesn't is just  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  on its own, when it acts like the Win Key.

It's available free on the [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/app/microsoft-remote-desktop-10/id1295203466?mt=12) <- Web browser link, will reopen in App Store.
Interestingly, it's far better as a Mac app than the native Windows version.